# Setting a div with background image to 100% height

Tags: css

I want to set a background for the content of a page. The div with the background image has `class=history`. All the divs above "history" and history itself have height set to 100%.  However, the "history" div does not get the correct height.

Below is a sample of the code. I may be missing some relevant details but will add them once the solution is found. See also [the live page](http://dynamicsresolved.com/company/history/).

The CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background: url(cream_dust.png) repeat 0 0;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<html>
<body class="page page-id-41 page-child parent-pageid-8 page-template-default logged-in admin-bar">
<div class="wrapper-for-footer">
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
<div id="main" class="site-main">
<div id="primary" class="content-
```

Comment: Can you add some html markup to the question? That way it'll make sense to future visitors even if you've fixed the linked site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element that is set to `height: 100%` will only take up 100% of the vertical space of its parent.  If there's an element somewhere between `history` and `body` that doesn't have a height, then it won't be as tall as you're expecting.

The majority of the `history` element is floated content, so it has collapsed to only contain the non-floated content.

Add a clearfix to the `history` element.

`overflow: hidden`

or

```
.history {
    zoom: 1; // fix for IE
}

.history:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add `position:absolute;` to the `div` you are trying to give 100% height to.

EDIT:  you **need** to add `position:absolute;` to the `history` `div`

Comment: That seems like a half solution. It works but messes everything else up. Why does that work?

Comment: That's just how `divs` work. In order to have 100% height you must use absolute positioning. The other errors you are having stem from another root. Let me take a look and see if I spot something.

Comment: I found you a solution... remove `height:100%;` from `<body>` and then in your CSS, set this: 
`.page-id-41{background:url('http:.your-images..png')!important;}`